# Using Checkbox in php while inserting multiple values

Tags: php, checkbox

I have tried producing a form with the loop, when I process the input the checkbox values are not retrieving, it says invalid index.

Form:

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;i++){
echo '<td>';
echo '<input name="att[$i]" type="checkbox" id="att'.$i.'" value="1"/>';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<input name="rno[$i]" type="text" id="rno'.$i.'"/>';
echo '</td>';
}
```

Retrieveing:

```
for($j=0;$j<$count;j++){
echo $rno=$_POST['rno'][$j];
echo $rno=$_POST['att'][$j];
}
```

I don't know where the problem is...
The error message invalid index "att". What is the problem?

Comment: `$_POST['att'][$j]`? Unless `att` is a variable you can't access your posted values like this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `'att'` (string) rather than `att`:

```
for($j=0;$j<$count;j++){
    echo $rno=$_POST['rno'][$j];
    echo $rno=$_POST['att'][$j];
}
```